# codeigniter file cache vs database cache

Tags: codeigniter, caching

Is there any difference between codeigniter's file cache and database cache?

I'm pertaining to these codes.

```
$this->cache->file->save()
```

vs

```
$this->db->cache_on();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`db` class caches queries, `cache` class caches output data